# I wonder why $\omega$ is continuous iff each $\omega_{i_1,\dots,i_k}$ is continuous. (Calculus on Manifolds by Michael Spivak. continuity of $k$-form)

Tags: tensors, differential-forms

I am reading "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.

> Many similar considerations may be applied to a function $\omega$ with $\omega(p)\in\Lambda^k(\mathbb{R}_p^n)$; such a function is called a **$k$-form** on $\mathbb{R}^n$, or simply a **differential form**. If $\varphi_1(p),\dots,\varphi_n(p)$ is the dual basis to $(e_1)_p,\dots,(e_n)_p$, then $$\omega(p)=\sum_{i_1<\cdots <i_k}\omega_{i_1,\dots,i_k}(p)\cdot [\varphi_{i_1}(p)\wedge\cdots\wedge\varphi_{i_k}(p)]$$ for certain functions $\omega_{i_1,\dots,i_k}$; the form $\omega$ is called continuous, differentiable, etc., if these functions are.

$\omega$ is a function whose value is also a function.
$\omega_{i_1,\dots,i_k}$ is a real-valued function.

I wonder why $\omega$ is continuous iff each $\omega_{i_1,\dots,i_k}$ is continuous.
I wonder why $\omega$ is differentiable iff each $\omega_{i_1,\dots,i_k}$ is differentiable.

---

I wonder why the author defined $\omega$ is continuous iff each $\omega_{i_1,\dots,i_k}$ is continuous.
I wonder why the author defined $\omega$ is differentiable iff each $\omega_{i_1,\dots,i_k}$ is differentiable.

---

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is called continuous iff each $f_i$ is continuous.
We can prove the following fact:
If $f$ is continuous, then for any positive real number $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$ for any $x$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$.
So I think this definition is natural.

But the author didn't define the distance between $\omega(p_1)$ and $\omega(p_2)$ for arbitrary $p_1,p_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Spivak is giving a definition here.

Comment: Yes, this is the definition of a continuous $k$-form on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes. I mean I wonder why the author defined $\omega$ is continuous iff each $\omega_{i_1,\dots, i_k}$ is continuous.

Comment: Why not? This is one if the most obvious and low-tech definitions available. It’s just saying a form is continuous iff each component function relative to an obvious basis of forms is continuous.

Comment: If you want the general way of doing things, you’re going to first need to define the tangent and cotangent bundles, and understand their topologies and smooth structures. Then you can prove this as a theorem… but Spivak doesn’t cover this stuff in this book because that’s not his goal here. For more, you should look at his 5-volume beast (Vol 1 suffices though). But I suggest you stick with *Calculus on Manifolds* because it’s a prerequisite to his differential geometry volumes.

Comment: @peek-a-boo thank you very much for your comments.